# Adjusting Text Padding Below Text

Tags: html, css, text

So I have the title of an app (h1) and then underneath the title is a slogan (h2). I want the spacing between these two bodies of text to be closer. But the code is automatically giving the h2 a position on the page that can't be adjusted without adjusting the h1. How can I adjust the h2 relative to the the class (.mainBanner) and not h1.

Thanks for the help!

```
.mainBanner {
    background-image: url(/Users/omaramin/Documents/Competition/project/mainBanner.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 125px;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: Bariol;

}

h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Bariol;
}
```

Comment: Try using negative margin spacing. h2 { margin-top: -5px; }

Comment: Post your html either in this post or on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Cam please do not post answers in the comments. Post it as a proper answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @winterblood will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using negative margin spacing.

```
h2 { margin-top: -5px; }
```